# Content search webpart in office 365 developer site - no search results

Tags: search, search-results

I have a Office 365 developer site and I have activated the publishing features including cross-site publishing. I have created page based on "Article page" content type and published the page as major version. When I tried to search the content based on some texts in the article I don't get any results. I tried with Content search web part and tried to filter based on "Artcile page" content type and didnt get any results...

Now its almost a day and still the content doesn't showup on search results...Any ideas what could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: what happens when you search for *

Comment: Try to "ReIndex" the site from Search Settings page

Comment: @MaxMelcher I'm not getting any search results.

Comment: @404 how do you re-index search in site collection

Comment: See https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Manually-request-crawling-and-re-indexing-of-a-site-a-library-or-a-list-9afa977d-39de-4321-b4ca-8c7c7e6d264e?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA for reindexing options.

Comment: @MaxMelcher Re-indexing didn't work... im not getting any search results

Comment: a) can you access the content? b) is the site maybe excluded from crawling?